# angularjs select box default selection based on database id

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In view I have

```
...

<select ng-model="customer" ng-options="c.name for c in customers">
    <option value="">-- chose customer --</option>
</select> 

....
```

In controller I have

```
$scope.customers = [
    {"id":4,"name":"aaaa","isActive":1,"isDeleted":0},
    {"id":5,"name":"testxyz","isActive":0,"isDeleted":0},
    {"id":9,"name":"bbb","isActive":1,"isDeleted":0},
    {"id":10,"name":"asdfa","isActive":0,"isDeleted":0},
    {"id":11,"name":"asdfa","isActive":0,"isDeleted":0}
        ];
if ($scope.$id != null)
{
    Message.query({id: $scope.$id}, function(data) {                    
    if (data[0].id) {
        $scope.name = data[0].name;
        $scope.fromName = data[0].fromName;
        $scope.subject = data[0].subject;

// this line does not work because data[0].custID is database
// customer ID Foreign Key linked with this record
//   {"id":4,"name":"aaaa","isActive":1,"isDeleted":0}     

        $scope.customer = data[0].custID;

// this works as it is based on index
//$scope.customer = $scope.customers[3]; 

    } else {
        alert('Request Failed: ' + data.msg);
    }
});

}
```

Now when I try to edit the record and open view in edit mode with pre-filled fields from database, I will need to do default selection to SELECT Box which works fine on array index based but I need to do selection on Foreign Key bases

How can I default select Select box based on Foreign key, not index?

Comment: its shame my openID is not working again and I have to open stackexchange account to ask this question, don't know any other way, any idea how can I link my openID account with this one, so I can use both authentication(openID & stackexchange), if one does not work, I can use other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to modify your html as below and then it will work with your foreign key

```
<select ng-model="customer" ng-options="c.id as c.name for c in customers">

 $scope.customer = 9;
```